# Flash remove child from timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

I have 25 objects of movie clip class named drone, and when i click it, after 2 seconds I want the object to disappear. I also have 25 timers named countdown. Here is what i do:

```
function clickHandler (event:MouseEvent):void{
event.currentTarget.hp--;

if(event.currentTarget.hp <= 0)
{
    for(var i:int = 0;i<25;i++)
    {
        if(event.currentTarget == _drone[i])
        {
            countdown[i].start(); //start timer

        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my timer:

```
for(var i:int = 0;i<25;i++)
{
    countdown[i] = new Timer(2000);     
    countdown[i].addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerHandler);
}
function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void {
    //remove the drone I clicked
    //I also dont know which drone i'm clicking

}
```

What should I do in the timerHandler to remove the object I clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html). Use  the timer as key and movielcip as value.

```
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

function clickHandler (event:MouseEvent):void{
    event.currentTarget.hp--;

   if(event.currentTarget.hp <= 0)
   {
       for(var i:int = 0;i<25;i++)
       {
            if(event.currentTarget == _drone[i])
            {
                dict[countdown[i]] = _drone[i];//set the target mc here
                countdown[i].start(); //start timer
                break;
             }
        }
   }

}

function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void {

     var mc:MovieClip = dict[e.target] as MovieClip;//get the object been clicked

     if (mc && mc.parent) {
        mc.parent.removeChild(mc);//remove it
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

With minimal changes, set up an array to track the drones:

```
var arrayToRemove:Array = new Array();
```

and then in the click handler store drones to be removed in there:

```
arrayToRemove.push(event.currentTarget);
```

and in the timerHandler just remove the first element of the array:

```
removeChild(arrayToRemove.shift());
```

Since every delay is the same the order of the events and removals will be preserved. Although, it would probably be better to generalize the code using the above example and store all drones and timers in an arrays, so you can have any number of them.